# How much space I should leave for browser taskbar?

Tags: website-design, mockup, prototyping

Normally the height of a website wireframe is not a problem because we are expected to scroll. But what if the website is designed to fit the screen height? If we make a wireframe of a website that uses 1920x1080 or 16:9 as the base template, in that case, the browser taskbar and operating system (search-bar+bookmark-bar+window-panel+ OS taskbar+ notification panel etc) will take a lot of space from the desired height. The wireframe will only be realized best when the browser is in full screen mode. But we don't want the user to scroll down on the website. Even if the actual website fits only in the viewing area, how can we show that in a  wireframe image? How much space should we leave for the browser and OS taskbar?

Answer (score 2):

The simple fact of the matter is that there are too many screen sizes, from phones to large desktop monitors and everything in between, and differences in user setup for this question to be exactly answered with a specific number.

The more important thing is to **convey the design requirements to your frontend developer**. A good frontend developer can take the wireframe(s) and requirements given and make something that matches it as closely as possible, including keeping the entire site to a single viewport.

If you're trying to support every screen size (you probably should), it would be helpful to the frontend developer to provide additional wireframes of what the site should look like on smaller and different dimension screen sizes. He should be able to handle the in-between states.